# C# triple double quotes (three double quotes)

Tags: c#, string, format

What is the purpose of triple douple quotes `"""` in C#? It seems it is used for multiline text. But why not use single double quotes with `@"..."`?

```
string text = """
  some text
  some text
  some text
  """;
```

Comment: Because single quotes don't allow newline inside. This was a decision made long time ago, and cannot be changed now. That's why `"""` were introduced.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals

Comment: If I remember correctly, using triple double-quotes also allows you to align the start of each line in your multiline literal without introducing unwanted leading whitespace. I can't recall exactly how it worked but I saw a YouTube video on it a while back. Never used it myself so I can't provide details but that's something to consider.

Comment: Multiline is just one aspect. This way allows to use just any text and throw it in as raw string without the need to apply additional escaping. Just use a series of quotes longer then the longest quote series in your raw string. Does not need to be 3 can be 5, 10, or even more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Source: [C# 11 Preview Updates – Raw string literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/)

> If you work with strings literal that contain quotes or embedded
> language strings like JSON, XML, HTML, SQL, Regex and others, raw
> literal strings may be your favorite feature of C# 11. Previously if
> you copied a literal string with quotes into a C# literal, the string
> ended at the first double quote with compiler errors until you escaped
> each one. Similarly, if you copied text with curly braces into an
> interpolated string literal, each curly bracket was interpreted as the
> beginning of a nested code expression unless you escape it, generally
> by doubling the curly bracket.
>
> Raw string literals have no escaping. For example, a backslash is
> output as a backslash, and `\t` is output as the backslash and a `t`,
> not as the tab character.
>
> Raw string literals start and end with at least three double quotes
> (`"""..."""`). Within these double quotes, single `"` are considered
> content and included in the string. Any number of double quotes less
> than the number that opened the raw string literal are treated as
> content. So, in the common case of three double quotes opening the raw
> string literals, two double quotes appearing together would just be
> content. If you need to output a sequence of three or more double
> quotes, just open and close the raw string literal with at least one
> more quote than that sequence.
>
> Raw string literals can be interpolated by preceding them with a `$`.
> The number of `$` that prefixes the string is the number of curly
> brackets that are required to indicate a nested code expression. This
> means that a `$` behaves like the existing string interpolation – a
> single set of curly brackets indicate nested code. If a raw string
> literal is prefixed with `$$`, a single curly bracket is treated as
> content and it takes two curly brackets to indicate nested code. Just
> like with quotes, you can add more `$` to allow more curly brackets to
> be treated as content. For example:
>
> ```c#
> const int veryCold = -30;
> const int comfortable = 20;
>
> string jsonString =
>   $$"""
>   {
>     "TemperatureRanges": {
>       "Cold": {
>         "High": {{comfortable}},
>         "Low": {{veryCold}}
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   """;
> ```
>
> Raw string literals also have new behavior around automatically
> determining indentation of the content based on leading whitespace. To
> learn more about this and to see more examples on this feature, check
> out the [docs article Raw String Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals).

**P.S.** Thanks to [Roe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18278998/roe) and [ProgrammingLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/programmingllama) for pointing to this articles.

Answer (score 26):

I think a *simple example* can explain better than many a text.
Suppose we have a sql query which we want to keep in a good format
to be easy readable.

If we put it naive, it won't compile:

```
string sql = 
  "select id, 
          name
     from MyTable"; // <- Doesn't compile
```

We can use `@` to have *verbatim* strings which now compiles

```
string sql = 
 @"select id, 
          name
     from MyTable"; 

...

// A little bit different format somewhere else in c# code
string sameSql = @"select id, 
                          name
                     from MyTable";
```

But yet another problem arises: we have *different* strings and that's why
RDBMS will treat them as *different* queries, *both* versions will be parsed
and optimized, put into cache etc. So we have the *same* job done *several times* (and even worse: parsed queries cache can be flooded by *same* query in *different* formats and it'll be not enough space for other queries).

From `sql` we have

```
select id, 
          name
     from MyTable
```

From `sameSql` we have the same query but in a different format:

```
select id, 
                          name
                     from MyTable
```

Note that leading spaces are preserved (we used *verbatim* strings, right?) and that's a problem.

The solution is to use new `"""` construction

```
string sql = 
 """
    select id, 
           name
      from MyTable
 """; 

...

// A little bit different format
string sameSql = """
                    select id, 
                           name
                      from MyTable
                 """;
```

In both cases we'll get the *same* text

```
select id, 
       name
  from MyTable
```

the query will be parsed, optimized and put into cache just once, *c# code style ignored*.

Comment: Reasons for downvote: the answer explains just a single use case (the OP did not ask for) but makes no mention to other use cases (see comments of question) or to any documentation at all; second half deals with a goal only implicitly mentioned. And as there is, again, no reference to any documentation, it looks like the exploitation of a side effect, presented in "And voila!" style. Additionally, my way addressing a goal like yours would be to replace all whitespace (outside quotes) with a single blank, which is a much more reliable solution, can be done via regex or with iterative approaches